# Stanford Tagger with GATE

Tags: stanford-nlp, gate

I am using GATE for Arabic under Linux and when using Stanford Tagger there aren't any POS tags. All parameters were not changed (as default) what can I do to perform that task?
Does this problem depend on the parameters ? What installation directory of the tagger must be set in the taggerBinary parameter?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a new StanfordPOSTaggerPR in GATE and initialize the Tagger with the `arabic.tagger` model provided with the StanfordTagger.

The last version of GATE is the 8.0 and it uses the StanfordTagger 3.4. So you'll have to download the models provided with this version.

[image]

Next, you have to create a corpus pipeline with a SentenceSplitter and a Tokeniser (I've tried with the `UnicodeTokeniser` and the `RegExp SentenceSplitter`):

[image]

Finally, try the pipeline with a sample file:

[image]